# Value does not fall within the expected range - Exception for SharePoint Lookup Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am trying to copy data from one list to other list (both lists are on different sites) along with lookup columns. But, I am getting an error for lookup field as:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Code works and data gets copied for other non-lookup fields. I tried every possible way including increasing List View Lookup Threshold and all possible ways of code but still error persists at `ExecuteQuery()`.

Below is my code for lookup field:

```
if (field is FieldLookup && field.InternalName == "Country")
{
    var CountryLookup = (item.FieldValues["Country"] as FieldLookupValue).LookupValue.ToString();
    var CountryLookupId = (item.FieldValues["Country"] as FieldLookupValue).LookupId.ToString();
    FieldLookupValue flvRDS = new FieldLookupValue();
    flvRDS.LookupId = int.Parse(CountryLookupId);
    itemToCreate["Country"] = flvRDS;
    itemToCreate.Update();
    destContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `item` is the new ListItem you're trying to create on your target list.

But you're never in fact reading any value from `field` here! So basically, you're trying to set your new FieldLookup.LookupId with the item["Country"].LookupId, which should logically be empty at this moment.

Here's a method I use to retrieve a lookup field ListItem from a value, feel free to modify it to fit your need, since I don't know how you want to retrieve it (SPList is an alias for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List).

```
private ListItem GetLookupItem(FieldLookup lookupField, string lookupValue)
{
    string mappingField = lookupField.LookupField;

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List lookupList = Context.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(lookupField.LookupList));

    Context.Load(lookupList);
    Context.ExecuteQuery();

    ListItemCollection libListItems = lookupList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
    Context.Load(libListItems, items => items.Include(
        itemlookup => itemlookup.Id,
        itemlookup => itemlookup[mappingField]));
    Context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem mappedItem in libListItems)
    {
        object mappedField = mappedItem[mappingField];
        if (mappedField != null && mappedField.ToString().Equals(lookupValue))
            return mappedItem;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now that you have the corresponding ListItem, you can set your `item.LookupId` with its Id:

```
if (field is FieldLookup && field.InternalName == "Country")
{
    FieldLookupValue flvRDS = new FieldLookupValue();
    flvRDS.LookupId = GetLookupItem(field as FieldLookup, "France").Id; // here, dunno how you get your country's name
    itemToCreate["Country"] = flvRDS;
    itemToCreate.Update();
    destContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Feel free to add some more previous code if you want an answer more suited for your specific issue.

Comment: Actually item is the existing data in the list item from where I am reading and itemToCreate is the new item where I need to copy it. Also I am getting country name & Id in CountryLookup & CountryLookupId respectively. Just the thing is they are not getting copied.

Comment: Try retrieving the ID of the looked up item instead of the LookupId, as I did in my code.